# Auto populate the opportunity name

Tags: apex, force.com

When a user clicks the new button to create an opportunity, I want to autopopulate the opportunity name field for all my opps to "DO NOT MODIFY." Also, I want to carry over any existing functionality (say the account name) How do I do that?

Can I do URL hacking? The idea of overwriting the new button by visualforce / apex seems like extreme overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that URL parameter names (used in URL hacking) are not considered part of any API by Salesforce and so may change in the future.

But if you chose to use URL hacking, here is how.

An example URL (starting from Account ID 001i000000wF4mP) that would automatically populate the Opportunity name would be:

```
/006/e?retURL=%2F001i000000wF4mP&accid=001i000000wF4mP&opp3=DO+NOT+MODIFY
```

If this URL is in a Visualforce page you control then you can build it.

(You can find the required names like "opp3" by using your browser's "Inspect Element" on the field in the standard page. For custom objects, these field names are values that vary from org to org and so require more work to obtain.)

But if you want to create a new Opportunity through the normal (layout based UI) then you will have to override the Opportunity "New" action with a (nearly empty) page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="MyController" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

that uses a small controller to modify the URL:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/006/e');
        Map<String, String> m = pr.getParameters();
        // Keep existing parameters
        m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
        // Add Opportunity name parameter
        m.put('opp3', 'DO NOT OVERRIDE');
        // Turn off the override so you go to the default UI page (and not an infinite loop)
        m.put('nooverride', '1');
        return pr;
    }
}
```

The result is that the Visualforce page URL is initially opened but before anything is rendered redirects to the standard page but with the extra parameter added.

Comment: thanks keith. it seems like overkill to create yet another VF page to handle a redirect like that. I have a number of blank vf pages where i do very similar stuff. I wish there was something easier, so my admins could maintain it.

Comment: @nivyaj Yeah its a pretty convoluted solution. But Salesforce don't provide any other way to intercept requests AFAIK...

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do this a different way using workflow. When workflow runs after the opportunity is saved (after insert), have a rule run on Opportunity.Name that looks something like this:

```
"DO NOT MODIFY " & Account.Name " - " & Name
```

The above rule would put "DO NOT MODIFY" followed by a blank space, "Account Name", a " - " and whatever name the user entered for the opportunity. If you remove the `& Name` at the end of the work rule above, it would simply replace it without retaining anything the user entered for the Opp's Name.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that won't work. I already wrote a trigger to standardize the opp names already that's based on a number of variables. I don't want my users populating the field at creation though.

Comment: As you'll notice, as I stated above, if `& Name` is removed at the end of the workflow rule, the workflow removes anything a user attempts to populate the Opp Name with without you needing a trigger. You could simply set a default value on your page if you wanted.

Comment: not sure if i can set a default value for this type of std field.